# VCL RichEdit component suggestion

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, vertical-alignment, richedit

I tried to implement vertical paragraph alignment feature to TRichEdit control. It is such a headache. And i also need transparent background support from RichEdit control. Can you suggest any free or paid VCL RichEdit component that has full RTF support and transparent background support.

Comment: The [`TRichView`](http://www.trichview.com/) control is *not* a wrapper for the Windows Rich Edit control, I have been told, but it might work for you anyway. I have never tried it, but I guess you can download compiled sample demos and try those.

Comment: As far as I know, TRichView do not support transparency.

Comment: @tutalia: So you are interested in a [window-less Rich Edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787609(VS.85).aspx), or a custom control with similar behaviour?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: custom control with similar behavior.

Comment: I think you asked something similar a couple of days ago - Time to start thinking "I don't need a TRichEdit" I need a "Roll my own component" Its probably less time consuming to do that than spend days trying to make richedit do what it can't. Just a suggestion...

Comment: Delphi wraps quite backward Rich Edit control (2.0 in relatively modern D210) while MS keeps developing newer and newer versions. See overview of modern features missing from VCL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Indeed ! We are now in 2019 and Embarcadero is still lagging behind ... unable to propose a Richedit wrapper based on the latest standards and the latest DLL ... I would a expect a wrapper that is capable of accepting pasted pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPTools](http://wptools.com/) is a descent Rich Text Editor as it has much of the functionality of MS Word's RTF format. I don't recall how much it costs.

The main drawback I notices when working with it was some outline formatting issues.